# how to use pnpm workspace without publish to build with rely

Tags: typescript, monorepo, pnpm-workspace

I have a pnpm typescript monorepo project. There is an `foo` and `bar` program in packages file. Then the `bar` program is rely `foo` program. When I develop on local use `"foo": "workspace:^1.0.0` is working. But When I use `npx tsc` to build typescript, I get `not fund module foo`.

I search for many data that all said need to publish then can be use, but I don't want to publish because it just a side project, just use for me. So how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want workspace packages to work in TypeScript, you should use TypeScript project references: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html